# NSwindow re show multiple times from dock icon after closed

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, nswindow

```
//My code:

- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    if(flag==NO)
    {
         id window;

        NSWindow *w = window;

       for(w in theApplication.windows)
        {   if(w==[[theApplication windows]objectAtIndex:0])
            {
                [w makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]; 
            }
        }

    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender;
{
     return NO;
}
- (BOOL)applicationOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{

    return NO;
}
```

Problem Faced
-Above code shows untitled window
-If I remove `[w makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];` out of `if` condition then all windows with untitled window is displayed once
-Using open untitled method is not stoping  its window to show

Required
-I want only closed window to open

Comment: not clear, please explain a bit

Comment: You can subclass `NSWindow` and add a `BOOL` isClosed

Comment: above displayed code is in App delegate.m

-  i have 3 windows in my view hierarchy  so i want the window closed by user to open again when clicked on dock icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more Survey on mentioned code I found Solution which is as follows

-Methods used are proper
- To load your same screen again we need to find index of that screen in application.windows array.That can be done by using code:

```
for (int i; i<[[[NSApplication sharedApplication]windows] count]; i++)
    {
        if (yourwindow==[[[NSApplication sharedApplication]windows] objectAtIndex:i])
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",i);
           //i is your screen index
        }
    }
```

Now load window using index in mentioned code,it will also prevent show of untitled window

Note: finding index of window should be used after it loading method is Completed.